# Upload all the contents of a directory to the storage account container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I have the following structure

```
mf
├── dir1
│   └── file1
├── file1
├── file2
├── file3
├── file4
└── file5
```

Is it possible to upload only the content that is inside the mf folder by az cli commands to a storage account container?

Comment: Do you want to upload folder in that structure or full content in diff files in one file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload-batch):

Firstly, I have :

[image]

Then used :

```
az storage blob upload-batch --destination "name of container" --account-name "rithwik"  --source "C:\Users\Downloads\mf"
```

[image]

After Uploading:

[image]

If you want it in same structure with mf :

```
az storage blob upload-batch --destination "rithwik" --account-name "rithwik" --destination-path mf --source "C:\Users\Downloads\mf"
```

[image]

In Azure Portal:

[image]

Inside mf:

[image]

Inside dir1:

[image]